# Why do certain apps fill the background of Mission Control in Mavericks?

Tags: mission-control, skype

Certain apps (Skype, Office for Mac 2010 or something like that) fill the background of the screen when I open Mission Control. When Mission control is focused on the space the app is in, all is well. When I switch to a different space, however, this happens. It is consistent (i.e. the same apps always do this, every time), and annoying. I've tried to find workarounds, but I haven't came up with anything. Any help is much appreciated.

[image: screenshot]
(Note that I rearranged the window to hide my contacts, but it has the same effect with the window maximized or in full screen.)

Comment: They're all Microsoft applications? ;) I have that problem too, and (just out of speculation) I would say that they  weren't built quite right for OS X and thus they have a weird bug that causes that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to have been fixed in either Yosemite or the latest version of Office. I've been using this combination for some time now and have yet to encounter this. (I haven't tried Skype, though.)